# where does a user-defined type's metaclass' __new__ and __init__ get invoked?

Tags: python, types, cpython

I'm reading several articles to understand how class types are created in Python ([1](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/15/under-the-hood-of-python-class-definitions), [2](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/), [3](https://leanpub.com/insidethepythonvirtualmachine/read)), and following along Python's source code ([typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c3d9508ff22ece9a96892b628dd5813e2fb0cd80/Objects/typeobject.c)).

My Question: When a new user-defined type is created, where does its metaclass' `__new__` and `__init__` get invoked?

I'll explain:

say we have a simple user-defined type:

```
class A(object): pass
```

To create the type `A`, `type_call` is eventually invoked, with `type` as its first parameter. In this case, `type` is actually `PyType_Type`.

Inside `type_call`, `tp_new` is called, which in this case means a call to `type_new`.

Now, Inside `type_new`, the new type is eventually allocated with:

```
/* Allocate the type object */
type = (PyTypeObject *)metatype->tp_alloc(metatype, nslots);
```

And when `type_new` finishes, it returns `type` to `type_call`. Then, `type_call` calls `tp_init` - which means a call to `type_init`, which invokes `object_init`, that doesn't really do anything.

Somewhere, `type`'s `__new__` and `__init__` should be called. Did I miss these calls along the way, or are they called outside `type_call`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tp_new` and `tp_init` are the C-level counterparts of `__new__` and `__init__`. The calls to `tp_new` and `tp_init` *are* the `__new__` and `__init__` calls.

If you override `type.__new__` or `type.__init__` in a metaclass you define, the corresponding `tp_new` or `tp_init` slots in your metaclass will be set to C-level [functions](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Objects/typeobject.c#L6398) that search for and invoke your Python-level overrides.

Answer (score 1):

As [user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49661509/908494) explains, `tp_new` is the type slot method, and the default version of it for Python-defined classes looks up and calls the `__new__` method.

The idea of type slot methods isn't really explained all in a single place, but see [Type Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html) in the C API and [New Types](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html) in the Extending and Embedding docs.

You'll also want to read the specific entries on `tp_new` in both of those chapters, because it's a particularly special function.

If you want to see the source, most of the relevant stuff is in [`typeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c). Notice that the `__new__` wrapper is different from other Python method wrappers, and the name lookup doesn't call the generic special method lookup code, but the basics are still pretty similar.

Comment: Huh. I never really thought about how the lookup for `__new__` would need different handling from other special methods, and now that I'm looking at it, I'm surprised it almost (but not quite) boils down to "just do a normal attribute lookup". That interacts [pretty strangely](https://ideone.com/lK5ugm) with a metaclass `__getattribute__`.

Comment: @user2357112 Well, Python doesn't guarantee that special method lookup will be different from normal method lookup, it just refuses to guarantee that it _won't_ be different. And the `__hash__` rationale doesn't apply to `__new__`, so…